# Trace values of parameters

Tags: debugging

I would like to print the value of a register into the document for 'debugging' purposes. For counters I would use `\arabic{myCounter}`. But `\abovedisplayskip` is not a counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\the` to typeset  a value of a dimension for example:

```
\the\abovedisplayskip
```

Answer (score 6):

For debugging I often find `\showthe` to be more useful (as in `\showthe\abovedisplayskip`); it pauses the typesetting and displays the value on the console. For a LaTeX counter you would write

```
\showthe\c@foo
```

assuming you defined the counter as

```
\newcounter{foo}
```